# Can FactoryGirl check to see of models already exist in the database before creating new ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, factory-bot

I have the following factory setup:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :country do |f|
    f.name "USA"
    f.country_code "USA"
    f.currency_code "USD"
  end

  factory :region do |f|
    f.name "East Coast"
    f.country {Country.first}
  end

  factory :state do |f|
    f.name 'CA'
    f.region {Region.first}
    f.country {Country.first}
  end 

end
```

What I want to do in the region & state factories is to check if an entry already exists in the database for Country, if yes then use that and only if no entries are found should it create a new model.

Here is an example of what I have in mind, but not sure how to create this:

```
factory :state do |f|
  f.name 'CA'
  f.region {Region.first || Factory(:region}
  f.country {Country.first || Factory(:state}
end
```

The reason why I want to do this is to inject entries into my database which will populate form select fields & so that I can test using cucumber.

Comment: Why would you do this? I can't image a good reason to do that

Comment: Because of my database schema state cannot save unless region & country entries already exist. I need at least 3 state models for testing but only want to insert one row for region & country.

Answer (score 5):

You could use callbacks to accomplish this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :country do |f|
    f.name          "USA"
    f.country_code  "USA"
    f.currency_code "USD"
  end

  factory :region do |f|
    f.name "East Coast"
    after_build {|r| r.country = (Country.first || Factory(:country))}
  end

  factory :state do |f|
    f.name 'CA'
    after_build do |s|
      s.region  = Region.first  || Factory(:region)
      s.country = Country.first || Factory(:country)
    end
  end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need associations.
each :region belongs_to :state and each :state belongs_to :country
which have in return many states and regions.

You can then use these associations in your factory.

Check the Getting started guide: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md